# WPF Binding Привязка к ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

привет есть код

```
<ListBox  Name="dd"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=human}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding family}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

вот c# код

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            human();
            //dd.ItemsSource = human();
        }
        List<Human> human()
        {
            var T = new List<Human>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                T.Add(new Human
                {
                    name = "Alex" + i,
                    family = "Roibin" + i,
                    image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Data/img.jpg",UriKind.Relative))
                });
            }
            return T;
        }
    }
    public class Human
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string family { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage image { get; set; }
    }
```

Как правильно привязать в ХАML

```
dd.ItemsSource = human();
```

работает но не нужен

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны привязываться к свойству, поэтому давайте заведем его:

```
public IEnumerable<Human> Humans { get; }

public MainWindow()
{
    Humans = human();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Обратите внимание, что мы заполняем список значениями до вызова `InitializeComponent();`, лучше его сделать после инициализации, но тогда вам потребуется еще реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` чтобы оповестить окно об изменении списка

Теперь привязка:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Humans}">
```

Ну и чтобы свойство с таким именем все-таки было найдено, нужно где-то установить `DataContext`, например, в `Window`:

```
<Window ...
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Comment: Вы утверждаете что приведенный вами код рабочий?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, нерабочий код я бы не запостил. Естественно я его проверил.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, будьте добры, укажите что здесь по вашему не должно сработать

Comment: невнимательно посмотрел, минус снимаю, хотя подобные советы считаю сомнительной ценности. Колекцию хьюмансов нужно выносить в VM

Comment: Конечно, надо. Но, боюсь, ТС о MVVM пока не слышал

Comment: Так и не услышит, если на его вопросы будут так отвечать :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Humans = FillList();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }

   private ObservableCollection<Human> humans;
   public ObservableCollection<Human> Humans
    {
     get{return humans;}   
     set{
     if (humans == value) return;
      humans = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("Humans");
     }
    }
  private ObservableCollection<Human> FillList()
  {
   var T = new ObservableCollection<Human>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            T.Add(new Human
            {
                name = "Alex" + i,
                family = "Roibin" + i,
                image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Data/img.jpg",UriKind.Relative))
            });
        }
        return T;
  }
}
public class Human
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage image { get; set; }
}
```

Cоответсвенно:

```
<ListBox  Name="dd"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Humans}">
```

Comment: Вы хотите записать `List<>` в `ObservableCollection<>`, они разве совместимы? Ну и, собственно, как UI должен узнать о том, что коллекция изменилась целиком? `INPC` не имплементирован, а `INCC` оповещает только об изменении содержимого коллекции...

Comment: На счет функции Вы правы. Моя ошибка.Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Простите необразованого, что такое INPC и INCC?

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged`